# Google Sheets formula to round up to the nearest whole number?

Tags: google-sheets

Selling something by bundles of 10, and want to try and calculate how many bundles and the price.

32 purchased / 10 bundle size = 3.2

Want to round 3.2 up 4 bundles.

Tried the ROUND() function but that rounds up and down. I always need to round up.

Searched around, found ways to prevent rounding, but not how to specifically round up always to nearest whole number.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way.

`=ROUNDUP(3.2,0)`

Which results in 4. The ROUNDUP function takes an argument, which tells it how many decimal places to round to. 0 means whole number.

> Rounds a number to a certain number of decimal places, always rounding
>   up to the next valid increment.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093443?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [CEILING](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093471):

```
=ceiling(32/10)
```

result: `4`.

The difference between CEILING and ROUNDUP is essentially in negative numbers (CEILING rounds these towards 0).